# Unmet peer dependency installing react

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have two related questions. I'm installing react into a new empty project. I only have a basic `package.json` file in the folder, nothing else.

The message I get is

> +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-addons-css-transition-group@0.14.x || 15.x.x

First, question: Am I interpreting this correctly? Message is saying, either install the `react-addons-css-transition-group@0.14.x` package or install react version 15.x.x?

Second, by running `npm install react --save`, I installed react version 15.5.4. If my interpretation of the message is correct, why am I getting the message? I already have react 15.5.4 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first interpretation is correct. You can have either version.

But it's not complaining about `react`, but complaining about `react-addons-css-transition-group`. You need to install `react-addons-css-transition-group` along with `react`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the first point. I realized the issue was with the css transition group but if you look at the info on npmjs.com, this package is deprecated. I also found that the issue can be resolved by upgrading npm to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article that indicated that this is a bug and can be solved by upgrading to the latest version of npm.

So I removed all my npm packages which was not issue for me because it's a new project. If you have an existing project, you may not need to do that. I just wanted to have a clean slate.

I then cleaned up my package.json and upgraded npm on my computer to latest version using [npm-windows-upgrade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade).

I then did a clean `npm install react` and this time I did not get any error messages.